# Blazor Server-side and Firebird Encoding issues

Tags: c#, encoding, blazor-server-side

I am retrieving data from a Firebird database and I'm having trouble to get things to work properly.

I've set the database encoding to `None` and update some values with accents in my DB editor (Flamerobin or other) and store this string:

```
1_éöüäà
```

Then I load the data in my Blazor app using default `Firebird` client and `Dapper`. If I use a connection string with `Charset=None` encoding, the loaded string now is

```
1_�����
```

Ok so let's change the charset to `Charset=ISO8859_1` and relaunch the application. I now get:

```
1_éöüäà
```

GREAT - not all is lost, it seems it is stored in DB with `ISO8859_1` encoding...

So now, let's edit the value in the Blazor app and store it in the DB still with `Dapper` and `ISO8859_1` charset. I use the SAME connection string for loading and storing data - here is what I actually save (I copy-pasted Dappers' query parameters here):

```
3_éöüäà
```

When I check what I have in my DB now (Flamerobin) I get the following strings:

```
3_Ã©Ã¶Ã¼Ã¤Ã
```

Ok so the encoding was changed somewhere... After I reload the data in my App, I get the SAME result as above - so encoding was somehow messed up while saving and reloading from DB, using the SAME encoding?! How could that be?!

So well, why not try using `Charset=None` again to load the data in the app? Guess what, the result is now

```
3_éöüäà (in App)  and 3_Ã©Ã¶Ã¼Ã¤Ã (in DB)
```

What? Why would I see the string CORRECTLY by setting `Charset=NONE` in the connection string but, as it was saved with `Charset=ISO8859_1` from the App?

Note that on a WINFORMS app, the exact same manip works the same whether I load/save the data with `Charset=None` OR `Charset=ISO8859_1`... Result is alwas as desired : `1_éöüäà`.

EDIT: I see the SAME result on my Blazor page AND in the VS debugger console everywhere. I therefore doubt that would be a rendering issue on the browser side - it really is on the .Net / server side that things are happening!

Comment: [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/) - it's 3rd millennium nowadays…

Comment: @JosefZ very constructive answer... How to fix a car? Well, buy a new one!

Comment: Note that `3_Ã©Ã¶Ã¼Ã¤Ã ` is a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) of the following kind:  `'3_Ã©Ã¶Ã¼Ã¤Ã '.encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8')` returns `'3_éöüäà'` and vice versa `'3_éöüäà'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252')` returns `'3_Ã©Ã¶Ã¼Ã¤Ã\xa0'`. Examples in Python, sorry. Do not buy a new car; just use appropriate tools repairing a broken one…

Comment: @JosefZ So what exactly is your solution? Charset NONE should be UTF-8 as far as I understood. So why would loading the default charset NOT work in the first place?

Comment: And btw, this does not explain why storing and loading with the SAME charset modifies the string, as charset of the DB is "None" it is supposed to take the RAW data...